# Use az webapp deployment source to deploy code from git but when the app is in a git repository subfolder

Tags: python, git, azure, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm trying to deploy code from my gitlab CI runner to Azure.  I'm using the `az webapp deployment` to do the job:

```sh
az webapp deployment source config --branch master --manual-integration --name [myWebApp] --repo-url [git url] --app-working-dir [folder] --resource-group [myResourceGroup]
```

But there is a problem, the default working directory is the git 's root folder. My application is inside a child folder from root. I check the [command configuration](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/cli/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest) and I saw `--app-working-dir` which does what I want, again, but only works if `--cd-project-url` is set (I don't need and I'm not using  VSTS). Also, there is no example available of using this config. I'm looking to have a command set similar to what I used when deploying via azure cloud shell: `cd <app-folder>; az webapp up --sku B1 --name <app-name>`. There is a way to do the deploy in a simpler form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .deployment file in your root directory of your git repository. And add the project sub folder in the configuration. It will work then.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will need to configure Kudu somehere or this is already embedded on azure system?

Comment: No you need to add a . Deployment file in your root directory of git solution e.g  [config]
project = WebProject/WebProject.csproj